# How to compile c code in visual c++ express 2010

Tags: c

I am trying to compile c code in VS C++ express 2010 but I get the following error trace:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test4, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>cl : Command line error D8045: cannot compile C file 'test4.c' with the /clr option
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I try and compile with cpp extension I get this error trace:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test4, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  test4.cpp
1>c:\documents and settings\rkelly1\desktop\io\test4\test4\pt_ioctl.c(86): error C2664: 'CreateFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\documents and settings\rkelly1\desktop\io\test4\test4\pt_ioctl.c(98): error C2664: 'CreateFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\documents and settings\rkelly1\desktop\io\test4\test4\pt_ioctl.c(138): error C2664: 'OpenServiceW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [9]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\documents and settings\rkelly1\desktop\io\test4\test4\pt_ioctl.c(196): error C2664: 'GetSystemDirectoryW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CHAR [80]' to 'LPWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\documents and settings\rkelly1\desktop\io\test4\test4\pt_ioctl.c(203): error C2664: 'lstrcatW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CHAR [80]' to 'LPWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\documents and settings\rkelly1\desktop\io\test4\test4\pt_ioctl.c(208): error C2664: 'CopyFile' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'LPCTSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\documents and settings\rkelly1\desktop\io\test4\test4\pt_ioctl.c(236): error C2664: 'CreateServiceW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [9]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>test4.cpp(27): error C3861: 'kbhit': identifier not found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Your errors when compiling with a .cpp extension indicate that you are mixing up `wchar_t` and `char`.  Even if you compile this file as a C file, you'll need to fix those errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your project, make sure you create it as a Win32 program and not a CLR application. This setting can be changed under project properties.

Propeties -> Common Language Runtime Support is the setting you are looking for.
Set it to none.

Answer (score 5):

/clr means use the .Net runtime - not the c language runtime!

Just call the file .c and it will work, there is a flag to stop you using any c++ features.

Go to properties -> c/c++ ->advanced -> compile as and select 'c'

Comment: I did as you suggested and I still am getting Command line error D8045: cannot compile C file 'test4.c' with the /clr option

Comment: remove the /clr optiuon - it's for MSFT's strange mixture of c++ with C#/.net

Comment: Note that by default the Visual C++ compiler compiles files with a .c extension as C and files with a .cpp extension as C++.  You shouldn't need to change this setting if you use those two standard extensions.

Comment: @James - I think the compile-as-c-flag warns on things like "//" comments even with a .c file (been a few versions since I used it)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should remove `/clr`, it's not what you're after.

To respond to the problem underlying the question: you are passing a `char` array to an LPWSTR and LPCWSTR and LPCTSTR, which are all double byte char arrays, so `wchar_t*` of some form or other (if UNICODE is defined, otherwise the last one is just plain `char*`-like).

You will either have to undo your UNICODE define (not recommended) or convert the `char[]` and `char*` to `wchar_t` based types